# filter request get using wildcard

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to create a function in an Python API that should query an endpoint and get all items that contain a filter wildcard.

for example if I run

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data_product/'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I get all the items, i.e.

```
{
    "count": 5,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data_product/5/",
            "internal_format": false,
            "prov_report": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/prov-report/5/",
            "last_updated": "2022-01-28T16:59:18.173266Z",
            "name": "find/csv",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "updated_by": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/",
            "object": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/object/311/",
            "namespace": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/namespace/3/",
            "external_object": null
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data_product/4/",
            "internal_format": false,
            "prov_report": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/prov-report/4/",
            "last_updated": "2022-01-24T11:21:49.541879Z",
            "name": "test/csv",
            "version": "0.0.1",
            "updated_by": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/",
            "object": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/object/34/",
            "namespace": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/namespace/3/",
            "external_object": null
        },
       ...
```

I would like to find the item/s that contain a string.
For example I would like to find that item whose name contains "find"

I tried

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data_product/?name=find'
```

but returns 0 items found

Comment: I think it only searches for "name": "find".
Are there any other options, or would you mind filtering with python

Comment: I think best practice would  be adding this functionality within the django registry used here... but I have no access to that.. I can only make a get request.

Comment: This is rather unclear. If the API supports this then use it; if it doesn't, you can't (though obviously your Python code can implement a filter to only pull out the parts of the response which are useful to you). What exactly is your question?

Comment: implement a filter to only pull out the parts of the respons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you get all items as a string, which you can filter using python:

```
import json
name = "find"
results = json.dumps([obj for obj in json.loads(response)["results"] if obj["name"].startswith(name)], indent=4)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data_product/5/",
        "internal_format": false,
        "prov_report": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/prov-report/5/",
        "last_updated": "2022-01-28T16:59:18.173266Z",
        "name": "find/csv",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "updated_by": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/1/",
        "object": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/object/311/",
        "namespace": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/namespace/3/",
        "external_object": null
    }
]
```